# Binance API Invalid JSON Syntax on Kline/Candlestick data

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, binance-api-client

**Objective**: Generate C# classes using [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/) for [Binance REST API](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#klinecandlestick-data) in order to deserialize data from exchange.

So far i have implemented all C# classes using JSON Utils in order to deserialize data from exhange. All except one **(Kline/Candlestick data)**

Problem: When i paste code from bellow in JSON Utils i am getting error: **Invalid JSON Syntax**

```
[
    [
        1660284300000,
        "323.50000000",
        "323.70000000",
        "322.40000000",
        "322.40000000",
        "757.16400000",
        1660284599999,
        "244731.13410000",
        536,
        "205.39900000",
        "66395.15700000",
        "0"
    ]
]
```

Is this valid JSON file and how to generate C# Class using this output in order to deserialize data?

**EDIT**

According to all your statements (esp. **freakish**), here is the source if anyone needed:

```
class B_KlineData
{
        public long openTime { get; set; }
        public string openPrice { get; set; }
        public string highPrice { get; set; }
        public string lowPrice { get; set; }
        public string closePrice { get; set; }
        public string volume { get; set; }
        public long closeTime { get; set; }
        public string quoteAssetVolume { get; set; }
        public long numberOfTrades { get; set; }
        public string baseVolume { get; set; }
        public string quoteVolume { get; set; }
        public string ignore { get; set; }

  
public static IEnumerable<B_KlineData> ParseBinanceResponse(string json)
        {
            var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
            var root = jsonDoc.RootElement;

            foreach (var array in root.EnumerateArray())
            {
                yield return new B_KlineData
                {
                    openTime = array[0].GetInt64(),
                    openPrice = array[1].GetString(),
                    highPrice = array[2].GetString(),
                    lowPrice = array[3].GetString(),
                    closePrice = array[4].GetString(),
                    volume = array[5].GetString(),
                    closeTime = array[6].GetInt64(),
                    quoteAssetVolume = array[7].GetString(),
                    numberOfTrades = array[8].GetInt64(),
                    baseVolume = array[9].GetString(),
                    quoteVolume = array[10].GetString(),
                    ignore = array[11].GetString()
                };
            }

         }

}
```

**CALLING Method**

```
var jsonData= await market.KlineCandlestickData("BNBUSDT", Interval.FIVE_MINUTE,null,null,2 );
            
IEnumerable<B_KlineData> bdata = B_KlineData.ParseBinanceResponse(jsonData);

            foreach (var item in bdata)
            {
                txtLog.Text += item.openTime.ToString() + "\n";
                txtLog.Text += item.openPrice.ToString() + "\n";
                txtLog.Text += item.highPrice.ToString() + "\n";
                txtLog.Text += item.lowPrice.ToString() + "\n";
                txtLog.Text += item.closePrice.ToString() + "\n";
                txtLog.Text += item.volume.ToString() + "\n";
                txtLog.Text += item.closeTime.ToString() + "\n";
                txtLog.Text += item.quoteAssetVolume.ToString() + "\n";
                txtLog.Text += item.numberOfTrades.ToString() + "\n";
                txtLog.Text += item.baseVolume.ToString() + "\n";
                txtLog.Text += item.quoteVolume.ToString() + "\n";
                txtLog.Text += item.ignore.ToString() + "\n";

            }
```

What I'm not sure about is whether it is possible to optimize this code even more?

Comment: It is indeed valid JSON. It's an array of arrays. Mixing string values and numeric isn't great though. Depending on the serializer used, it might or might not present an issue deserializing it (JSON.NET can deserialize that as a `double[][]` but System.Text.Json cannot without first setting `NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString`)

Comment: You will probably have to do some low level JSON manipulation. This is not a random mix of values. Each index has a concrete meaning. And array is used probably to save space (keys take place while they are not needed). I doubt any automatic "to object" deserializer can handle this properly. I'll post an example on how to handle it later.

Comment: Thanks, i am trying to define class on proper way but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right

Comment: Btw, I don't think you will be able to achieve this with this JSON Utils thingy. It seems to have limitations, and this is a good example. Also, as a side note: your `int` fields should definitely be `long`.

Comment: Correct, thanks. I will try with real time data to see will i be able to deserialize data

Comment: Also, what JSON package do you use? System.Text.Json? And what .Net version?

Comment: `B_KlineData` is an object (represented in JSON by `{` and ending with `}`). There are no objects in your JSON, only an array of arrays (an array starts with `[` and ends with `]`).

Comment: Ok I got it. So i have to create a class that can handle array of arrays in order to deserailize

Comment: No class will work with this case, because you don't have JSON `{}` object here. AFAIK no automatic deserializer will work in this case. But it is doable manually. One more time: what JSON package and what .Net version do you use?

Comment: Oh i see now, i do not have object, so i have to do it manually. Sorry, struggling with this. I am calling https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BNBUSDT&interval=5m&limit=1   using last Visual Studio 2022, i believe .net6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Binance returns an array of arrays of mixed values. These are not random values though. Typically you would get an array of objects like

[ { "openTime": 1660284300000, ... } ]

but if the array is big then you pay the price for those keys, which are not really needed. You can choose to drop keys and turn that object into an array, where each index has a concrete meaning. And this is what Binance does.

Unfortunately, typical automatic Json deserializers (for C# or not) don't work with such serialization variants. One way would be to deserialize this into `object[][]` double array, but this is awkward and also inefficient (boxing and other unnecessary allocations) and you still have to convert that double array into `B_KlineData` objects. The pro way is to do manual low level Json manipulation. Assuming you use System.Text.Json it can be done as follows:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

public static IEnumerable<B_KlineData> ParseBinanceResponse(string json)
{
    var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
    var root = jsonDoc.RootElement;

    foreach (var array in root.EnumerateArray())
    {
        yield new B_KlineData
        {
            openTime = array[0].GetInt64(),
            open = array[1].GetString(),
            high = array[2].GetString(),
            low = array[3].GetString(),
            ...
        };
    }

}
```

So as you can see lots of manual work (you have to specify the meaning of each index manually). But you can't run away from it anyway, if ultimately you want to deserialize this into `B_KlineData`. Well, it could be automatized somewhat, but AFAIK no Json lib does this. I might be wrong though.

Btw, your `int` fields should be `long`. And you can also add a proper validation inside `ParseBinanceResponse` function.

Note that other packages (e.g. Newtonsoft.Json) should allow low level Json manipulation as well. The general idea stays the same though.

Comment: Thanks for very clear explanation. Will try both ways using example you provided and using Newtonsoft.Json.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize like this data to c# class like this:

```
 public class ClassName
{
    public object[][] PropertyName{ get; set; }
}
```